# Html img srcset, does not show small image for mobile

Tags: html, image, srcset

My code shown below works fine on desktop computer, raplacing images with different sizes when I resize window.

But it does not work when I open website on mobile. On mobile web browser image with 'xlg' name is beeing loaded. Instead I would like of course the 'sm' image to be loaded.

Can anyone tell me, where is the problem ?

I also used

```html
<picture><source></source></picture>
```

but in this situation I must present image in this way.

```html
 <img 
      srcset="sm.jpg 768w,
              md.jpg 1024w,
              lg.jpg 1440w,
              xlg.jpg 1600w"
      sizes="(max-width: 768px) 768px,
             (max-width: 1024px) 1024px,
             (max-width: 1440px) 1440px,
             (min-width: 1441px) 1600px"
      src="sm.jpg"
      alt="">
```

Why for mobile, it shows me xlg.jpg image ? Does anyone know ?

Comment: Hi @theurgicus it will heavily depend on which mobile device you are testing. Perhaps you are using a browser that doesn't support this. [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset)

Comment: Hi. It is Samsung mobile phone. Using Samsung web browser and Opera mini browser. I got the same effect, 'xlg' images are being loded. : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your comment correctly, then those browsers plain simply don't support the srcset. If you check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) then you see that Opera Mini and the default Android browser don't support that functionality.

So you are probably looking for something that can never work.

Comment: Wow, great chart :)  Thanks. Yes I think it clearly explains the situation. You are the hero :) Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this for the dynamic images. 
[HTML  srcset Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp)
This example works for me in desktop and mobile correctly.

From the example, your code may looks like this:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1440px)" srcset="xlg.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="lg.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="md.jpg">
    <img src="sm.jpg" alt="" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

Comment: Thank You. Yes I also embed pictures the way You have mentioned. But in this case I must embed pictures using srcset.